# UTF-8 encoding issue rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Currently i am upgrading my application to rails 4 from rails 3.after the upgrade got the following issue in so many places.

"incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8"
Any idea on this?